# How to convert api response (Binary) for image to imageview Bitmap in android

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I try to convert like

```
byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decode(buildImageResponse, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedBytes , 0, decodedBytes.length);

holder.ivAssets.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

**Am getting this error** --
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64

Comment: If you have any questions please put them in your post.

Comment: does backend add info at the start of the base64 string? (not to uncommon to see something like `data:image/jpg;base64,` then you need to remove that part before you use Base64.decode

Comment: @MeetParsaniya it's too long days ago but not get solution for this. Instead of moved different function